# SQL ORACLE grouping by row values (values are a same, but important is ordering a data)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below values and i want to group them by urlid and status values.
I have used a group by function that these did not  work for me.
I have tried use a lag and lead methods but i cant handle that.
A same ouptut i can receive using a python3 script, but i does not work in cloud and i have to download all table to generate that. Is it possible to do that in ORACLE11 database?

```
CREATE TABLE test_group_by (
urlid text,
status text,
date_scraped date)

INSERT INTO test_group_by (urlid, statuses, date_scraped)
values
('1','active','2019-06-15'),
('1','active','2019-07-15'),
('1','active','2019-08-15'),
('1','inactive','2019-09-15'),
('1','active','2019-11-15'),
('1','active','2019-12-15'),
('2','active','2019-06-15'),
('2','inactive','2019-07-15'),
('2','active','2019-08-15')
```

[image: On right there is a output which i want to get]

Comment: You have tagged the question "oracle", but the DDL is not consistent with Oracle.

Comment: Thank you. This is really great :) I have prepared question in my home , so there is reason why i am using a wrong ddl

Comment: In Oracle, [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) are written like `date '2019-06-15'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands.  One solution is the difference of row numbers:

```
select urlid, status, min(date_scraped), max(date_scraped)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by urlid order by date_scraped) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by urlid, status order by date_scraped) as seqnum_s
      from test_group_by t
     ) t
group by urlid, status, (seqnum - seqnum_s)
order by urlid, min(date_scraped);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fea4654f1875b52190544783341f7406) is a db<>fiddle.  It uses Postgres because your DDL does not work for Oracle.

Comment: Thank you. This is really great :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two statuses then you can use following:

```
Select urlid, statuses, 
       min(date_scraped), 
       max(date_scraped)
  From
  (Select t.*, 
          Sum(case when statuses = 'active' then 0 else 1 end) as sm
     From your_table t)
Group by urlid, statuses, sm
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you, i will try this technique as well but i can not be sure that there would be only this values in these field in future.